# What are my options for merging subsets of repositories?

Tags: reactjs, git, version-control, architecture, single-page-application

This question is more of an application architecture and source control type of question.

I have 2 Github repositories, one is a React single page application and the other is for a React website. For my single page application, I am making the code publicly available and the application links to its repository. For my website, I want to keep the repository private but incorporate the single page application into it so people can use it without having to download and build code.

**Can I get some options on how to merge changes to the single page application repository with the website repository?**

So far I am just merging code to the website manually by copying it over and pushing the code, but that is a problematic way of doing things. Neither repo is completely up and running yet, so there is still time for me to make architecture changes. Maybe there are git commands to handle everything?

Any help is appreciated, including suggested architecture/repo changes.

Comment: I have a similar situation, where one repo has a subset of the code from another repo. The solution I use the cherry picking. In one sandbox, you can have two remotes, so you can cherry pick commits from one to the other quite easily. Proper merging is not an option: the commits from one and the other should have no common history.

Comment: Mind you, I'm now in the process of changing all this to make my life easier: I'm removing the subset from the larger Git repo, and making the other project a dependency instead. After having used my subset scenario for years, I would strongly advise against using it.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Could you give more detail for your solution of making the project a dependency?

Comment: Making the project a dependency all depends on your code structure. In Python, that would mean checkout both sandboxes separately, and pip install both. For your single page web app, can you have your two sandboxes live side-by-side in some way, with the two configured to both be active? I don't know the technologies you're using, so I can't help with the actual "how" for your project.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best option here would be to use `git cherry-pick`, but in an automated way:

- Build a simple script that listens for [push events via git webhooks](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhook-events-and-payloads#push), from your single page repo. That way you can get the merge-in-master event automatically
- Get the hash of that commit
- Plug that hash into the `git cherry-pick` command applied on your private website repo. You can apply this commit on a separate branch in this repo, and merge it in master when you think it's appropriate

Comment: Nice solution, I like the automation you get with the webhooks!