# Use a single repo with multiple projects

Tags: github, architecture

I have a repository called Notifications whose sole job is to send notifications / emails . I want to use that code at several other repositories so that when I update Notifications repo, all other repos use that code directly from github so that there is just a single source of truth. I am not able to understand how to achieve this. Can somebody please help?

Answer (score 0):

Best practice here is to package the code in the Notifications repo into an artifact, and then import that as a dependency in all the projects you need it.

If you have a code that cannot be packaged so straight-forward, you can sync the repos by installing a web-hook on the Notifications repo, which will be triggered whenever a merge in master (or any other event) happens.

The web-hook code will take the hash of the commit, and it will apply that commit to all the repos you need.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66282202/what-are-my-options-for-merging-subsets-of-repositories/66307688#66307688) is a similar post that you can check out.

It takes a bit of scripting work, but I think it's a viable solution.